# UIAlertController Hierarchy Errors

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I'm having issues presenting a `UIAlertViewController`. I get the following error when trying to execute the function:

> 2018-12-19 12:06:55.752953+0000 LoopUltimate[2545:108128] Warning:
>   Attempt to present  on
>    whose view is not in
>   the window hierarchy!

```
func enableDNDAlert(){
    //Check if DND is enabled in Firebase Remote Config
    if DNDSet.contains("no") {
        print("DND enabled")
        let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Enable Do Not Disturb and return to Loop",message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Enable", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            self.enableDND() }))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true) {}
    } else {
        print("Hidden")
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `enableDNAAlert`?

Comment: @RobertDresler That function is just below the enableDNDAlert()